# How to export result obtained from Python into excel

Tags: python, excel, plot, analysis, transfer

I did some analysis of my .txt file using python. Each data produced a set of results. I need to transfer the whole results into a single excel file. You can see my results from this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgYxv.png). Also, I want to mention each txt file name along with the results in the excel sheet. Can anyone help this matter ?

Comment: You can use the CSV format.  Print values separated by commas, copy to a file with a `csv` extension, and then open with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are using pandas. Pandas have a build in function to export to excel.

```
df_excel.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

If you want to add the name of the textfile, simply add the name to the corresponding rows.

Comment: Yes. I am using pandas. The issue, I am not converting the .csv file to an excel sheet.I did a few analyses on each .csv file. Each .csv file produced 4 answers (say, A,B,C,D). I need to put these answers from all .csv files into an excel sheet.  Can you suggest any code for it ?

Comment: I would save the 4 answers in a new dataframe and the apply .to_excel when loop is finished. However you can also append to an excel sheet using pandas.

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)

Comment: Hi. It works well to an extent. Thanks for the suggestion. But amongst the four sets of results, only one is saved in the excel file. Can you give some insight on how to add a loop before exporting it?